# Restlet client use authentication key

Tags: java, restlet

Using restlet JEE 2.3.2.

I have a client id and secret to interact with the server restful API. Submitting that info gets me back an authorization key that must be used for subsequent request. In curl, I can make queries using that key and can get data back:

```
curl -XGET "Authorization c79cec57-a52f-4e04-f3ca-55ea2a202114" "https://some/restful/endpoint"
```

How do I set my client resource to submit that authorization key? The online docs doesn't seem to cover this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

if the scheme is not important, you can use a "Custom" scheme, (as it is mandatory in HTTP specification"). In order to avoid the warning "scheme is not supported by restlet engine", just register one, as follow:

You can achieve what you need using a "custom" scheme, as follow.

```
    // Declare a custom Authenticator helper, if it is not standard
    Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredAuthenticators().add(new AuthenticatorHelper(ChallengeScheme.CUSTOM, true, false) {});

    // set up the reusable challenge response
    ChallengeResponse cred = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.CUSTOM);
    cred.setRawValue("12344");

    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8183/");
    cr.setChallengeResponse(cred);
    cr.get();
```

If you want an empty scheme, you can do as follow:

```
    ChallengeResponse cred = new ChallengeResponse(new ChallengeScheme("",""));
    cred.setRawValue("12345");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think that you can use challenge response as described since such feature builds the `Authorization` header using format `Authorization: Scheme ChallengeResponseContent`:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(resouceURL);
String token = "myToken";
ChallengeResponse cr = new ChallengeResponse(
             ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
cr.setRawValue(token);
resource.setChallengeResponse(cr);
(...)
```

As a matter of fact, Restlet requires a challenge scheme that will be added before the token (or something else) within the value of the header `Authorization`. See extract from class `AuthenticatorUtils#formatRequest`:

```
public static String formatRequest(ChallengeRequest challenge,
        Response response, Series<Header> httpHeaders) {
    String result = null;

    if (challenge == null) {
        Context.getCurrentLogger().warning(
                "No challenge response to format.");
    } else if (challenge.getScheme() == null) {
        Context.getCurrentLogger().warning(
                "A challenge response must have a scheme defined.");
    } else if (challenge.getScheme().getTechnicalName() == null) {
        Context.getCurrentLogger().warning(
                "A challenge scheme must have a technical name defined.");
    } else {
        ChallengeWriter cw = new ChallengeWriter();
        cw.append(challenge.getScheme().getTechnicalName()).appendSpace();
        int cwInitialLength = cw.getBuffer().length();

        if (challenge.getRawValue() != null) {
            cw.append(challenge.getRawValue());
        } else {
    (...)
```

In your case, I think that you need to build the header `Authorization` by yourself as described below:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(resouceURL);
String token = "myToken";
resource.getRequest().getHeaders().add("Authorization", token);
resource.get();
```

You can also implement a custom client resource for your needs in order to automatically apply the token:

```
public class ProtectedClientResource extends ClientResource {
    private String token;

    public ProtectedClientResource(String uri) {
        super(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public Response handleOutbound(Request request) {
        if (token!=null) {
            request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", token);
        }
        return super.handleOutbound(request);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I've add the header via
`resource.getRequest().getHeaders().add("Authorization", token);`
 but get the following error:

Jun 01, 2015 10:49:27 AM org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils addExtensionHeaders
WARNING: Addition of the standard header "Authorization" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.

Comment: I have also tried 
`ChallengeResponse cr = new ChallengeResponse(
             ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);

cr.setRawValue(token);
resource.setChallengeResponse(cr);` but get the following error: WARNING: Challenge scheme HTTP_Bearer not supported by the Restlet engine.

Comment: Yes, but with OAuth bearer, you will have something like that: `Authorization: Bearer mytoken`...  Even if you have the message (you don't have to put the oauth extension in the classpath), the header is added to the request...

Comment: I am using maven and I have not added anything more than the org.restlet and various of the representation extentions. The `HTTP_Bearer not supported by restlet engine` occurs when I call resource.get(), right before that I see the server is responding with a 401 "The request requires user authentication" so it appears it doesn't like the format, perhaps the "Bearer" string in the authentication ... I only need the token string

Comment: Yes, I think that you shouldn't use this since it's not what you expect. For your use case, I think that the only solution is: `resource.getRequest().getHeaders().add("Authorization", token);`. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, that is the 1st thing I tried ... produced the following error: `Jun 01, 2015 10:49:27 AM org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils addExtensionHeaders WARNING: Addition of the standard header "Authorization" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API`

Comment: Are you sure of the expected format for the header `Authorization`? Is it custom token-based authentication, OAuth, ...?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of the format ... I have verified it via curl (OP). I submit a request for token from the server using a shared clientId/secret as query parameters using POST with no authorization required (i know its not secure since its transmitted plain text, but it's a 3rd party service). I then get the token to use on subsequent request using format `Authorizaton: <tokenString>`

Comment: OKay! In fact, I made work the format `Authorizaton: <tokenString>` with Restlet 2.3.2 with the extension `org.restlet.ext.httpclient`. Can you make a try? You just need to add the dependency within your `pom.xml` file. I guess that you used the default http client connector...

Comment: I've added the dependency, still get the same `Addition of the standard header "Authorization" is not allowed.` on the get() method: I'm obviously not setting something up correctly if you are getting it to work. Can you post your example as an answer so I can compare and accept it.

Comment: Hi Micho. I made some tests and it appears that the restriction was added in version 2.3.2. It works for me only with version 2.3.1. I uploaded my test project to github. See this URL: https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/restlet/test-restlet-auth-token.

Comment: For your information, I also opened an issue in the Restlet github itself since I'm not really "pleased" with this: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1086. I'll keep you informed...

Comment: Thank you ... it worked as soon as I switched to 2.3.1 ... glad my code was okay, thought I was going insane for a moment.